# In Update Sentences - Transaction (Process ID 64) was deadlocked

Tags: c#, sql, deadlock, parallel.foreach, database-deadlocks

I am receiving the next random error "*Transaction (Process ID XX) was deadlocked on lock resources with \ another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction*"

This code is sending a massive number of emails, and updating 2 tables (one setting the notification flag to 1, and the another one storing the email sent - for each employee).

In the code looks like the emails are being sent correctly, and the problem is in the two queries to update the tables above.

How can I keep the parallelization feature (needed for performance reason) without loss some records updated? It is admissible to loss some performance if it is needed.

The next example code is:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;

Parallel.ForEach(listEmployees, options, item =>
{
       MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
       {
            ExecutionTaskId = 2,
            From = example@example.com,
            To = item.email,
            BodyDesc = template.Body,
            SubjectDesc = template.Subject,
            Status = 0,
            CreatedBy = item.persNbr,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        };

        SendMail(mail);
});

private static void SendMail(MailMessage item)
{
      System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

      ........

      msg.To.Add("to@example.com");
      msg.Body = "body";
      msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
      msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(example@example.com);

      item.BodyDesc = "body";
      item.SubjectDesc = "subject";
      
      using (var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SettingsRepository.GetSetting("WEB_SMTP")))
      {
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            item.Status = 1;
            item.SentDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (item.ObjectTable.Contains("var_control"))
            {
                 psn.NotificationSent = 1;
                 MailRepository.UpdatePayslipNotification(psn);
                 MailRepository.Update(item);
            }
            else
            {
                  p6n.NotificationSent = 1;
                  MailRepository.UpdateP60Notification(p6n);
                  MailRepository.Update(item);
            }
      }
}

public static void UpdatePayslipNotification(var var1)
{
    .........
    builder.Clear();
    builder.AppendLine("Update [example].[table_example]");
    builder.AppendLine("SET [example].[table_example].[NotificationSent] = " + 1);
    builder.AppendLine("WHERE [example].[table_example].[Id] = " + var1.Id);
    
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
          sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
          sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
          sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
          sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          sqlCommand.CommandText = builder.ToString();

          sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     ........
}

public static void Update(MailMessage mail)
{
    .........
    builder.Clear();
    builder.AppendLine("delete from [example].[MailTemp]");

    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
          sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
          sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
          sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
          sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          sqlCommand.CommandText = builder.ToString();

          sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, 
    SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTransaction))
    {
         sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[example].[MailTemp]";
         sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

         sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
    }

    builder.Clear();
    builder.AppendLine("Update [MailMessage]");
    builder.AppendLine("SET [MailMessage].[To]=[example].[MailTemp]. 
    [To],[MailMessage].[Status]=[example].[MailTemp].[Status], 
    [MailMessage].[SentDate]=[example].[MailTemp].[SentDate], 
    [MailMessage].[ErrorMessage]=[example].[MailTemp].[ErrorMessage], 
    [MailMessage].[SubjectDesc]=[example].[MailTemp].[SubjectDesc], 
    [MailMessage].[BodyDesc]=[example].[MailTemp].[BodyDesc], 
    [MailMessage].[From]=[example].[MailTemp].[From]");
    
    builder.AppendLine("FROM [example].[MailMessage] INNER JOIN 
    [example].[MailTemp] ON [example].[MailMessage].[Id]= 
    [example].[MailTemp].[Id]");

    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
          sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
          sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
          sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
          sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          sqlCommand.CommandText = builder.ToString();

          sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    sqlTransaction.Commit();
}
```

**--- Partial Solution ---**

(The original problem was solved using MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2, but there are a few added problems because of parallel DB reading are returning fake values. Trying to lock the parallel reading the program returns an generic error about parallel situation:

```
One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1 list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
```

```
object locker1 = new object();
object locker2 = new object();

var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;

Parallel.ForEach(listEmployees, options, item => 
{
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
      {
          ExecutionTaskId = 2,
          From = example@example.com,
          To = item.email,
          BodyDesc = template.Body,
          SubjectDesc = template.Subject,
          Status = 0,
          CreatedBy = item.persNbr,
          CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
      };

      SendMail(mail, locker1, locker2);
});

private static void SendMail(MailMessage item, object locker1, object locker2)
{
      System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

      ........

      lock (locker1)
      {
        // Get Access to DB - Read a record
      }

      
      using (var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SettingsRepository.GetSetting("WEB_SMTP")))
      {
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            item.Status = 1;
            item.SentDate = DateTime.Now;

            lock (locker)
            {

                if (item.ObjectTable.Contains("var_control"))
                {
                     psn.NotificationSent = 1;
                     MailRepository.UpdatePayslipNotification(psn);
                     MailRepository.Update(item);
                }
                else
                {
                     p6n.NotificationSent = 1;
                     MailRepository.UpdateP60Notification(p6n);
                     MailRepository.Update(item);
                }
            }
      }
}
```

**How can avoid these fake results from DB? How can I lock DB access using TheodorZoulias solution provided?**

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the time-consuming operation that incentivized the parallelization of the loop? Is it the `smtpClient.Send(msg);` command?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias . Yes, it is.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias New information added. Please, Would you mind to take a look?

Comment: Could you include in the question a minimal example that reproduces this error? Or, if you think that's it's beyond the scope of this question, you could open a new question about this specific error (together with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of course).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks so much for your response. I will try to clarify you the problem. From Partial Solution section you can check the code. 
I created 2 lockers outside of the Parallel and pass them to SendMail (inside parallel). 
Inside SendMail --> First - I lock the access to the DB (to do a get), unlock it. 
Second - I send an email. 
Third - I lock the access to the DB (to do 2 updates) and unlock after. 

Since I pass the 2 locker as parameter, program returns error message above... I think it is the same question, but would you prefer that I open another question? Thanks again

Comment: Using more than one lockers comes with the danger of deadlocks. See the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). My suggestion would be to protect all access to the database with a single locker.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias. But I need to follow the next flow --> get a record first, send an email after, and update 2 flags then. I cannot lock all process because I need "send an email" has to be parallelizated. Could I lock and unlock the "get" first and the "2 updates" then separataly using the same object (just locker1)? That will be enough? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, using the same locker in multiple places is perfectly fine. The basic idea is that only one thread will be allowed to enter in any of these protected sections at a time. When a thread has acquired the locker, all other threads that want to do the same will have to wait for their turn, in roughly FIFO order.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias. I cannot describe how much I am grateful to you :). I will check the new code monday. Mmmmm... last question please - When I defined the lockers outside of the Parallel and then I passed them to SendEmail(mail, locker1, locker2) as a parameters, I received the error message above. Therefore, should I think that it was because I used 2 lockers, right? Not because I defined the lockers outside and passed them as parameters.... Thanks Thanks

Comment: To be honest I have no clue about the origins of this error. It's the first time I'm seeing it. If you manage to create a minimal demo that reproduces the error, I might be able to play with it and reach to some conclusion. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245497/discussion-between-elias-mp-and-theodor-zoulias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the  time-consuming operation is sending the email, and updating the database is relatively fast, you could serialize the database-updating operations by using a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement):

```
object locker = new();
Parallel.ForEach(listEmployees, options, item =>
{
    MailMessage mail = new() { /*...*/ };
    SendMail(mail);
    lock (locker)
    {
        UpdateDataBase(mail);
    }
});
```

In the above example a dedicated `object` locker is used. You could also use as locker the `listEmployees` or the `options`, provided that you don't use the same instance anywhere else for unrelated synchronization purposes.

Comment: Thanks Theodor, It looks like is working. But it is strange, after 16.000 emails sent, 16000 records should be updated but it was updated just 15.999. Could you please give me a hint about what it is happening? In any case, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi Theodor. I was creating the locker inside of SendMail() Method. It looks like it is not working, my assuming is that I am creating a locker object per thread that it is not the idea. I have created the locker object outside the Parallel.ForEach and pass it as parameter (I updated my question to show you) but Parallalel returns an error.
I realized that we avoid the collisions using a MaxDegree of Parallelism to 2.

Comment: @EliasMP yes, if you create a different locker before each `lock`, it's practically a no-op. The lock will be acquired immediately every time, and no mutual exclusion will ever take place. In order to `lock` effectively, you should have a dedicated locker for each resource that you want to protect. In this case the resource is *"get access to the database"*.